# Monitor a service from a remote streaming server?

Tags: monitoring

My client uses a 3rd party to stream their radio station. Recently then have complaints about service outage in different global locations.

Does anyone know of a service I can use to monitor the remote audio stream coming from the streaming server?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like Nagios or Zabbix to periodically (every minute or two) connect to the port the streaming services uses.  Connection ok = good result. Connection refused or timed out = bad result and you can throw an error with whatever action... email, text message, or just logging it.

Comment: I only have a URL like this, http://subdomain.example.com/jw.php?channel=mymusic - can I use this... or is there a way to tell what port is being used?

Comment: When the URL is up does it return a 200 OK, and when it's down does it report a 500, or something other than 200?  If yes then you can absolutely use it.

Comment: Thanks - sounds good. I might give one of those a go... although they look rather complex. I just found a php script that will retrieve headers for a remote file. If I stick it on cron I think that might do the trick. I found the script at http://bit.ly/9oDhX0 if anyone is looking for something similar.